# Auditing with Envers and Hibernate Spatial 4

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers, auditing, hibernate-spatial

I'm attempting to use Envers to set up Auditing on my Hibernate entities. However, I'm getting the error:

> Could not determine type for: geometry, at table: Location_AUD, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(geom)]

Hibernate is happy with the geometry type I'm using without the auditing, but Envers seems to be having trouble with it.

Does anyone know if Envers works with Hibernate Spatial 4? If it does, perhaps someone can spot the issue with my code.

```
@Audited
@Entity
public class Location {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_LOCATION")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_LOCATION", sequenceName = "SEQ_LOCATION", allocationSize = 1)
    Long id;

    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
    Geometry geom;

    ...
}
```

I'm using Hibernate 4.2.5 with HibernateSpatial 4.0.0 M1

Comment: I have same error with spatial. Please tell me if you find answer. I will also.

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet. I'm considering telling envers not to audit the Geometry column and creating a custom getter that envres then audits (eg return a String of the geom as WKT).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having this exact same problem.  Manually adding a Hibernate `@TypeDef` annotation for the geometry type seems to have worked for me.  For whatever reason envers does not automatically pick up the `GeometryType` mapping even though Hibernate core does. So for our application, I have:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "geo_element")
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_geo_element__id__element")
@TypeDef(name = "geometry", typeClass = GeometryType.class)
public class GeoElement extends Element {

  @Type(type = "geometry")
  @Column(name = "data")
  private Point data;

  //...
}
```

We are using Hibernate 4.1 with Hibernate Spatial 4.0-M1 running on top of Spring 3.1.3 and configured using Spring's LocalSessionFactoryBean.

Comment: Thanks for that. We ended up auditing the Location table (with the geometry) manually. I'll accept the answer as it appears to be the solution (although I haven't tested it).